# Trying to update and select with PL/SQL pipelined functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" (
  id varchar2(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar2(255),
  website varchar2(500)
);
```

`website` can be in format such as `https://www.google.com`, if it is, then I need to update that row and set it to `google.com`.

Then, I need to count how many `name`s are with same updated domain. I need to do this as efficient as possible, so I'm experimenting with cursors and functions. If I have:

```
insert into MY_TABLE2(id, name, website) values ('1', 'a', 'dom1');
insert into MY_TABLE2(id, name, website) values ('2', 'b', 'dom2');
insert into MY_TABLE2(id, name, website) values ('3', 'c', 'dom1');
insert into MY_TABLE2(id, name, website) values ('4', 'd', null);
```

My code that is good should do this:

```
select mt1.name AS "SPOT NAME",  (select count(mt2.id) 
                                   from my_table2 mt2 
                                   where  mt1.website = mt2.website  )
 from my_table2 mt1;
```

I have following code:

This checks if the passed `website` satisfies criteria of a domain (lets assume regex is ok):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_domain_format(website my_table.website%type) RETURN varchar2 AS
v_is_in_domain_format boolean;
v_bool_as_varchar varchar2(5);
begin
    v_is_in_domain_format := regexp_like(website, '^[a-z0-9][-a-z.0-9]*[a-z0-9]$') and not regexp_like(website, '\.\.');
    IF v_is_in_domain_format THEN
        v_bool_as_varchar := 'true';
    ELSE
         v_bool_as_varchar := 'false';
    END IF;

    RETURN v_bool_as_varchar;
end is_domain_format;
```

Then we have actual formatting of a `website` to a domain:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION formate_url (website_ my_table.website%type) RETURN varchar2 AS 
v_domain varchar2(255) default null;
BEGIN
  v_domain := REGEXP_REPLACE(website_, '(http[s]?://)?(www\.)?(.*?)((/|:)(.)*|$)', '\3');
  RETURN v_domain;
END formate_url;
```

Then I have nested table:

```
CREATE TYPE t_spot AS OBJECT (
  v_id varchar2(255),
  v_name varchar2(255),
  v_domain varchar2(255)
);
```

And finally a pipelined function:

```
CREATE TYPE t_spot_tab IS TABLE OF t_spot;

create or replace function f_get_spots_piped
              return t_spot_tab PIPELINED as

    type r_spot is record ( v_id my_table.id%type,
                            v_website my_table.website%type);
 
   cursor c_spots_unformated is select id,website 
                                      from my_table 
                                      where website is not null and is_domain_format(website) = 'false';        

begin
  for spot_unformated_domain in c_spots_unformated loop
    update my_table set website = formate_url(spot_unformated_domain.website) where spot_unformated_domain.id = id;
  end loop;  


 for i in 1 .. 5 loop
  --this is only for a test...
  PIPE ROW (t_spot(1, 'a','b'));
 end loop;
 RETURN;
end;
```

I don't understand why do I get following error:

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.F_GET_SPOTS_PIPED", line 13
ORA-06512: at "SYS.F_GET_SPOTS_PIPED", line 13
14551. 00000 -  "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query "
*Cause:    DML operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update
           cannot be performed inside a query or under a PDML slave.
*Action:   Ensure that the offending DML operation is not performed or
           use an autonomous transaction to perform the DML operation within
           the query or PDML slave.
```

Is this by design or I made a mistake somewhere?

I mean, if this exception is expected, how can I write PL/SQL function which will effectively update and select?

At the end I need something following:

```
Name| Domain | Number_of_occurances_of_that_domain
```

So the query with pipelined function should be looking something like this:

```
select myTable.v_name as "Name", myTable.v_domain as "Domain", (select count(myTable1.v_id) 
                                                                    from f_get_spots_piped()   myTable1 where myTable.v_id=myTable1.v_id) as "Number_of_occurances_of_that_domain "
```

Edit1

Thanks @Litlefoot for giving good explanation!

However I have tried both options and they are failing with similar message as before.

Attempt1.

Added pragma_transaction to piped function, like so:

```
create or replace function f_get_spots_piped
                  return t_spot_tab PIPELINED as
    
     pragma autonomous_transaction;
```

Attempt2.

Creating a procedure which will do the updates and then calling it from piped function.

```
create or replace procedure update_spots as 
    
    pragma autonomous_transaction; 
    type r_spot is record ( v_id my_table.id%type,
                            v_website my_table.website%type);
 
   cursor c_spots_unformated is select id,website 
                                      from my_table 
                                      where website is not null and is_domain_format(website) = 'false';        

begin
    
  for spot_unformated_domain in c_spots_unformated loop
    update my_table set website = formate_url(spot_unformated_domain.website) where spot_unformated_domain.id = id;
  end loop;  

end;
```

And original function:

```
CREATE TYPE t_spot_tab IS TABLE OF t_spot;

create or replace function f_get_spots_piped
              return t_spot_tab PIPELINED as
    
                                       

begin

  update_spots;

 for i in 1 .. 5 loop
  PIPE ROW (t_spot('a','b'));
 end loop;
 RETURN;
end;
```

It fails when I do this:  `select * from f_get_spots_piped() ;`

Thank you again for your answer, hopefully you can point me in good direction from here, since I wasted some much hours setting up this query :(

Comment: "I don't understand why do I get following error" - it is clearly described in the error message: *DML operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update cannot be performed inside a query or under a PDML slave*. What is not clear? And why do you want to have a function with side-effects? It's at least not expected behaviour and especially in pipelined function that is intended to be a row source.

Comment: Ok, my apologize, it is clear if i didn't make any error that would cause this. If that is how pl/sql works then ok, my bad. This is my second day with pl/sql. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want a piece of code that returns data to have a side effect of updating data?  Side effects are normally things that you want to minimize.  Having code scan the table every time it is queried just to see if there is invalid data would also generally be a major performance issue.  You'd normally want to ensure data was in the correct format at load time and then just report on that data at query time.

Comment: @JustinCave Hey Justin, well, the assignment is to do a single query/pl-sql function which will do the update and return result set, which can be used in Java app. I have no idea any more how to perform such operation in a single go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error description explains it; though, as you didn't understand what it said, here's a simple example:

This is a sample table:

```
SQL> select * From test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK
      7566 JONES      MANAGER
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK
      7902 FORD       ANALYST
```

Function updates that table and sets jobs into lowercase, returning number of updated rows. This is, basically, similar to your function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number
  2  is
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    update test set job = lower(job);
  6    l_cnt := sql%rowcount;
  7    return l_cnt;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.
```

If you call the function in a query (i.e. in `select` statement), you get THE error:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;
select f_test from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.F_TEST", line 5
```

DML that's being performed in that function is, obviously, `update`. Error says that you can't do that **inside a query**, and query is `select f_test from dual`.

However, it would work if you called the function from within PL/SQL:

```
SQL> declare
  2    result number;
  3  begin
  4    result := f_test;
  5    dbms_output.put_Line('result = ' || result);
  6  end;
  7  /
result = 5               --> this is number of updated rows

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH      clerk            --> jobs are now lowercase
      7566 JONES      manager
      7788 SCOTT      analyst
      7876 ADAMS      clerk
      7902 FORD       analyst
```

Let's revert changes (i.e. jobs are uppercase again):

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.
```

Error description also says that you can *overcome* the issue if function was declared as an autonomous transaction. What's that?

> Autonomous transactions allow you to leave the context of the calling transaction, perform an independant transaction, and return to the calling transaction without affecting it's state. The autonomous transaction has no link to the calling transaction, so only commited data can be shared by both transactions.

([Tim Hall](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions) describes it better than me).

OK, let's do it:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number
  2  is
  3    pragma autonomous_transaction;          --> here
  4    l_cnt number;
  5  begin
  6    update test set job = lower(job);
  7    l_cnt := sql%rowcount;
  8    commit;
  9    return l_cnt;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Now, you can call the function from a query (remember, it raised an error before):

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
         5          --> 5 rows updated
```

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * From test;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH      clerk
      7566 JONES      manager
      7788 SCOTT      analyst
      7876 ADAMS      clerk
      7902 FORD       analyst

SQL>
```

---

That's how it goes; now, it depends on whether you can, or can not set the function to be an autonomous transaction (usually, we have it in procedures used for logging purposes or functions that are supposed to return sequential and non-gapeless data). It would probably be better if you leave the function *as is* and use it in PL/SQL; or, switch to a procedure and perform DML in there.

Comment: Actually, your answer with pragma autonomous_transaction did work. I forgot to add commit; :D It was late last night and I didn't notice. Tnx!